# Fetch database column comments with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to fetch the comments set on table columns in database (preferably MariaDB) with Sequelize ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with sequelize-auto to build your models from your DB. It will retrieve comments

Comment: I don't work with sequelize anymore :) thanx for answering this though. I'll upvote and validate answer but, I have no means to check if it works !

Comment: I can confirm it works, i use it every day. But thanks for the trust^^